# Outlook Mac on-premise unable to send when onsend addin is enabled

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I'm running Mac outlook 16.40 on an exchange server 216. I have an onsend add-in which works fine in OWA and Windows outlook. On Mac regular message send is blocked. I would not have expected the add-in to run because on-premise exchange server is running API 1.5 and Mac Outlook client requires API 1.6. However, although the addin is not getting called at all, it somehow blocking the regular message send. The client is domain joined and the add-in is configured at enabled optional.

Any suggestions on how to keep the add-in enabled for OWA users and a pass-through for Mac users?

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue .We are able to repro this issue only first time outlook launch. Are you able to repro it always or in some specific scenario? It is not possible to run any addin on particular client only"

Comment: Yes, it happens always.

Comment: Can I get an update on this issue please? Is there a fix coming?

Comment: Hello, thanks for bringing this issue to our notice. We have added this to our backlog. However we do not have any timelines to share for the same.

Comment: What's that suppose to mean, backlog? This is blocking normal send and customer is uninstalling addin. Is there a workaround? This is a SEV1 incident and should be treated as such. Any onsend addin that's enabled for on-premise is causing this issue on the customer side. Please treat urgently.